# Why is Soapclient not recognizing my accountInfo object

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, soap-client

I am trying to create a Soap request to query an automotive vehicle api. Whenever I run the call I get a client error of the following.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'accountInfo' property in ...
```

However I have defined it as a property. Relevant lines below:

```
DEFINE ('API_ENDPOINT',"http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7a?wsdl");
DEFINE ('API_SECRET',"xxx");
DEFINE ('API_ACCTNO',"123456");
DEFINE ('DEBUG',"1");
$useridentification = array('accountInfo' =>array('_'=>"",'number'=>API_ACCTNO, 'secret'=>API_SECRET, 'country'=>'US', 'language'=>'EN', 'behalfof'=>'?'));
enter code here
$vinobject = array('vin'=>$vin);
$buildrequest=array($useridentification, $vinobject);
$client = new SoapClient(API_ENDPOINT);
$response = $client->describeVehicle($buildrequest);
```

Hopefully this is something obvious to those that work with soap APIs regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Screw SoapClient, using curl. Hope it workks for you.